# NSFetchedResultsController expects exact number of rows to be returned

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` configured to load a certain type of objects in a `UITableView`. Below is the code sample that does this:

```
    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[[FSRDataManager sharedManager] loadViolationsForSection:FSRViolationEntityUnitIdAttribute
                                                 success:^(BOOL successful, NSFetchedResultsController *results) {
                                                     weakSelf.violations = results;
                                                     weakSelf.violations.delegate = weakSelf;
                                                     [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

                                                     [weakSelf fetchViolations];
                                                 }
                                                 failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                     [weakSelf displayAlertForError:error];

                                                     [weakSelf fetchViolations];
                                                 }];
```

The `FRC` has a `sectionNameKeyPath` because I want to show data in sectioned format.

The `fetchViolations` fetches data from the server and stores it in the `Persistent Storage` and updates the `Managed Object Context`. On this update, I received a delegate call to `-controllerWillChange:` and `-controllerDidChange:` which is normal. However, when these changes happen, the tableview's `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is called.

In there I am returning number of rows which is not always the number of objects in a `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` object, like so:

```
        rows = 1;
        for (NSIndexPath *i in self.expandedIndexPaths) {
            if (i.section == section) {
                id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> s = self.violations.sections[section];
                rows += s.numberOfObjects;
            }
        }
```

As you see, I am checking to see if the `indexPath` is in an array and only then I add the `numberOfObjects` in that section info object to a fixed number, `(1)` in this case.

However, doing this throws a `CoreData` error and my `UITableView` goes all "wonky".

Here is the error thrown:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1314
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 6 from section 71 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
```

If I just return the number of objects as in the section info object, it works fine. Is there any way to bypass this? Let me return the number of rows I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't 'bypass' this, you just can't use that approach without modifying the FRC delegate methods in a similar way. The error indicates that you're trying to apply all of the FRC delegate callback changes to the table view even if your row count method does very specific filtering. This results in a mismatch between the change requests sent to the table view and the row count provided for each section.

The simplest option is to not use the incremental change callbacks from the FRC, instead simply call `reloadData` on the table view after each change reported by the FRC.

If you want to enable animation for individual changes then you need to filter those changes and only apply the ones which have a corresponding change to the row count.